# Esiste il modo di dire "diffida di chi non sa ridere di gusto"?

Tags: proverbs

Mio nonno ogni tanto diceva una frase del tipo:

> Non fidarti delle (o guàrdati dalle) persone che non sanno ridere di gusto.

Esiste un simile modo di dire?

Comment: "Chi non ride mai non è una persona seria" "Fryderric Franicszek Chopin - http://www.accademiadellarisata.it/aforismi_frasi_celebri.asp

Comment: @Gio Bella, però mio nonno intendeva che le persone che non ridono spesso fanno cattiverie

Comment: @Gio: La frase è bella, ma quelli di accademiadellarisata.it non hanno idea di come si scriva il nome di Chopin: Frédéric François (o, se proprio si preferisce la versione polacca, Fryderyk Franciszek).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ho trovato in questo [Saggio di fisiognomonia e patognomonia, ossia Dei mezzi per conoscere le interne facolta e le malattie degli uomini dalle loro esterne apparenze](https://books.google.it/books?id=mHleAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=non%20fidarti%20delle%20persone%20che%20non%20ridono&source=bl&ots=y1VH-QH1vs&sig=tuX9p-V__i4NNFRAN-PM66OhV1c&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy4_6m3ejXAhXHOxQKHQdMDSQQ6AEIRTAH#v=onepage&q=non%20fidarti%20delle%20persone%20che%20non%20ridono&f=false) datato 1837 il seguente passaggio a pag. 116:

> Chi ride volentieri ma non immoderatamente è d'indole affabile e
>   spirito mediocre. I caratteri austeri non ridono che colle labbra, i
>   crudeli non ridono che nell'atto di far male. "**Non fidarti troppo,
>   dice Lavater, di un uomo che non sorride mai con amabilità; la grazia
>   del sorriso è il vero termometro della bontà del cuore, della nobiltà
>   del carattere**"- L'uomo che ride ad alta voce è bugiardo, dice
>   l'almanacco di Benincasa; e non è forse detto privo di fondamento,
>   come è vero che chi grida ha il torto.

Non sono un esperto ma penso che l'autore del libro si riferisca a [Johann Kaspar Lavater](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Kaspar_Lavater) pastore protestante vissuto nel '700 e studioso di fisiognomica.

Comment: Fantastico, grazie!